# dwm - Kill all windows for a tag

Tags: window-manager, dwm

In [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org/) is there a way to kill all windows with a particular tag? Example would like to kill all windows tagged with 2.

This would simulate the kill workspace feature that is available in many other tiling windows managers.

Answer (score 1):

Dwm doesn't have that functionality by default.

You can create a file named `wipetag.c` and add the following:

```c
static void wipetag(const Arg *arg);

void wipetag(const Arg *arg) {
  Client *c;

  for (c = selmon->clients; c; c = c->next) {
    if (c->tags & 1 << arg->i) {
      if (!sendevent(c, wmatom[WMDelete])) {
        XGrabServer(dpy);
        XSetErrorHandler(xerrordummy);
        XSetCloseDownMode(dpy, DestroyAll);
        XKillClient(dpy, c->win);
        XSync(dpy, False);
        XSetErrorHandler(xerror);
        XUngrabServer(dpy);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Include the file in `config.h`:

```c
#include "wipetag.c"
```

Then you can add a shortcut that calls the `wipetag` function:

```c
 static Key keys[] = {
    { Mod1Mask|ShiftMask,    XK_1,             wipetag,          {.i = 0} },
```

Adding the argument `.i = 0` will wipe the first tag, `.i = 1` the second and so on.

Comment: Can't this be made into a patch file, so that people don't have to copy paste the code each time ? Or is there already a patch file ?

Comment: I've written this code earlier today, I might submit it as a patch later if I can't find one that already does this.